Simplify repetetive jQuery functions
I'm sure this will be obvious to most of you. But I couldn't figure it out for I'm a beginner with JS and jQuery.
I've got a lot of repetitive functions all targeting specific elements (the same way, though). Let's say it's a really simple function. We're adding/toggling the class .add to an element #there by clicking the element #here. This goes on with another group of elements #here2 and #there2 and so on.

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#here").click(function(){
    $("#there").toggleClass("add");
  });
  $("#here2").click(function(){
    $("#there2").toggleClass("add");
  });
  $("#here3").click(function(){
    $("#there3").toggleClass("add");
  });
/* and so on */
});


Is there a simple way to achive what I'm looking for? Thank you. :)
I was trying to use a variable but couldn't figure out how to define it in this case. Nor did I manage to create a "meta-function" that replaces all the possible functions. :/

You can chain multiple selectors or use a class (selector) over the ID (selector)

Add event to class, not ID, and add data-target attributes to target elements: https://jsfiddle.net/579d032x/

@fdomn-m .here should trigger class change on .there, not on itself

@Justinas good catch - not as simple as it looked at first

@Justinas that seems to be the solution. I'll give that a try. Thank you! :)

I often time solve this by writing the target selector as an attribute. You would only need one click handler, for example for .classToggler and data-class and data-selector would control from the HTML which class to toggle on which element(s).
